# SectionList Duplicate items when adding new items to the list(Also in FlatList)

Tags: react-native, duplicates, rendering, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I am facing weird issue when rendering SectionList. When adding a new item to the list, previously added item duplicated. Not happening on vary first render and first item add, only happening when add new item on a second time and then going forward

Here is the code :

```
<SectionList
  ref={ref => this.sectionList = ref}
  sections={this.state.itemData}
  renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderMessages(item)}
  renderSectionFooter={({ section }) => this.renderSectionHeader(section)}
  inverted
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  onEndReached={() => this.handleMoreData()}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  style={{ flex: 1, margin: 5, opacity: 1 }}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
/>
```

I checked my array that i am passing, No duplicate data in it & also renderItem logs looks fine

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `keyExtractor`.

Try something like:

`keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}`

If your `this.state.itemData` elements have a unique identifier you could use that as a keyExtractor:

`keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}`

Also when adding new items to your list you might want to consider using `extraData` to make sure the sectionList will re-render

`extraData={this.state}`